# How to use a external variable into a SQL query's where condition?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I want to fetch data from PostgreSQL database through python script. In where condition I have to use a value from local variable called "lastrun" last run is nothing but I have stored the last time when the program gets executed in a  file. After read that file I stored that value in a variable called "lastrun" and I wanna use it in the query.

```
lastrun="06/11/2020 08:20:50.949881"
def doQuery( conn ):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT accountno,req, type, site,ref FROM accounts WHERE  created > lastrun")
    records=cur.fetchall()

print("Using PyGreSQL…")
import pgdb
myConnection = pgdb.connect( host=hostname, user=username, password=password, database=database )
doQuery( myConnection )
myConnection.close()
```

I tried but nothing works for me. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read https://pygresql.org/contents/tutorial.html#first-steps-with-the-db-api-2-0-interface? If not, then the 5th code sample displays passing variables correctly (**without** manual string formatting).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use python string formatting to achive this

```
lastrun="06/11/2020 08:20:50.949881"
def doQuery( conn ):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT accountno,req, type, site,ref FROM accounts WHERE  created > '%s'"%lastrun)
    records=cur.fetchall()

print("Using PyGreSQL…")
import pgdb
myConnection = pgdb.connect( host=hostname, user=username, password=password, database=database )
doQuery( myConnection )
myConnection.close()
```

for more info visit [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tutorial-postgresql-python).

Comment: Do NOT use string processing it is error prone and opens you to SQL injection hacks. Use a parameterized query. There are examples in the psycopg2 docs.

Comment: Can you please share me the resource relevant to my question? Thanks

Comment: I had shared link where you can find example of query but it's just basic string formatting of python. for that https://www.techbeamers.com/string-formatting-python/

Comment: The page linked to in the question is filled with examples of bad practice.